# Using "that of" to avoid repetition

Tags: phrase-usage, repetition

> Overpopulation is a real concern all across the globe, but the
> situation in poor countries is not comparable **to the situation in** rich
> countries.

I have written the above sentence but to avoid repetition I have altered it as follows:

> Overpopulation is a real concern all across the globe, but the
> situation in poor countries is not comparable **to that of** rich
> countries.

Is it correct use of "that of"? Can we always use "that of" in all cases? I mean, I usually see "that of" is used for the possessions but I used it for "the situation" which is not possessed by a country!

Comment: Your use of *that of* is generally correct, but there's something awkward about your phrasing: you say "the situation **in** poor countries, but "(the situation) **of** rich countries."  It should really be parallel: the situation of poor countries vs. that of rich countries.

Comment: I don't think parallel construction actually helps in this case. I didn't see anything awkward in the OP's sentence, but "the situation of poor countries" definitely falls strangely on my ear.

Comment: You could always say **to that _in_ rich countries** to keep the symmetry.

Answer (score 1):

Almost. Like the other commenters said, the correct way to write it would be:

> "...is not comparable to that **in** rich countries".

You're replacing "**the situation**" with "**that**".

A good way to see if it's correct is to try to reverse it:

> "...is not comparable to that of rich countries"

> "...is not comparable to **the situation** of rich countries"

Then you see that it does not align with the previous part of the sentence ("but the situation in poor countries...".